# Android: Updating a BaseAdapter's ArrayList properly?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, listadapter

I've seen many examples / tutorials that explain how you can update an `ArrayList` used by a `BaseAdapter`. For example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Item> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    //called to update the ListView
    public void resetList(ArrayList<Item> newList) {
        this.listData = newList;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

}

Another way is to clear and fill the original ArrayList where listData is currently pointing to and to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from the Activity's thread.

Why is this an often recommended way? What happens if I click on a ListView item directly after or while the ArrayList is being modified but before notifyDataSetChanged() is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling `resetList()` from Activity's (UI) thread, you cannot click an item in the middle of method ecexution, as clicks are processed by the same UI thread, therefore, you are able to perform a click only before or after the method execution.